# Detect if element with focus is a textbox

Tags: vb.net, focus, controls, element

How can I detect if the active element in my `VB.NET` app is a Textbox?

`Me.ActiveControl` and then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TypeOf`:

```
Dim isATextBox As Boolean = TypeOf Me.ActiveControl Is TextBox
```

Comment: @Justme You are welcome. (I have always found pretty curious the way in which typeof is used in VB.NET; mainly by looking at the way in which it is used in C#)

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be

```
If Me.ActiveControl.GetType() Is GetType(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox) Then 
    ' do stuff
End If
```